# NSIS installer shows "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: windows, cmake, cpack, makensis

I am beta testing a Windows application, and two users, so far, complain that running the installer displays that message: "This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher."

The installer is generated on **macOS 11.6.5** (Intel) with **makensis v3.08**, driven by **cmake 3.22.2**.

One user had the same build of Windows 11 as I do, and got the error. I don't.

They both have a x64-based PC.

The installer that is causing the problem can be downloaded there:

https://twistedwave.com/download/TwistedWave-Installer-27.0.12.exe

What could cause this message to appear?

Comment: The installer does not display that message, most likely Windows. Usually means unsupported CPU. Maybe they don't have wow64 installed?

Comment: Thanks @Anders. That is also what I had in mind, but the installer is a 32-bit application, and I thought it was always possible to run 32-bit apps on 64-bit versions of windows. According to [Wow64's wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64), "It is included in all 64-bit versions of Windows". Is that not true? Is there a way to check if it is installed, and how can it be installed if it is not installed?

Comment: wow64 is an optional components but it is normally installed by default except for some server versions.