# NSIS installer produces an app that can't run "This app can't run on your PC" "The executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"

Tags: nsis

Same request as: [NSIS installer shows "This app can't run on your PC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71927445/nsis-installer-shows-this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc)

Following the steps to create a basic "Hello, World!" NSIS installer produces an EXE that can't run on Windows 10. What flags are missing to create a basic do-nothing NSIS installer?

https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Category:Tutorials

Comment: Do other 32-bit apps work? Wow64 installed?

Comment: Yes! Other 32 bit apps work and WOW64 works as intended.

Comment: Compile Example1.nsi and upload it somewhere and I'll take a look.

Comment: So, I'd love to know more about why specifically the "Hello World" version doesn't work. Following the instructions to a tee here: https://www.conjur.org/blog/building-a-windows-installer-from-a-linux-ci-pipeline/ produce a working installer!

Comment: Post your code...

Comment: Sure thing! I appreciate the help. I'm cross-compiling an NSIS installer on Linux (via Docker) for Windows following this simple hello world example: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Simple_tutorials#The_bare_minimum


    `Outfile "hello world.exe"`
    `Section -Installer`
    `MessageBox MB_OK "Hello, World!"`
    `SectionEnd`


Compiled with: `makensis -V4 app/installer.msi`

Comment: The code looks fine, must be a problem with your crosscompiler setup.

Comment: Given that this works fine: https://www.conjur.org/blog/building-a-windows-installer-from-a-linux-ci-pipeline/
And the only changes are to the installer.msi file, I don't think it's the cross-compiler setup. It just seems that I need all that boilerplate.

Comment: Why do you keep talking about msi?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. The only way I found to solve it, was using MUI2.

A very minimal example that works for me is:

```
OutFile "installer.exe"

!include "MUI2.nsh"

# use at least one MUI2 page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

# example section
Section
MessageBox MB_OK "Hello world!"
SectionEnd
```